# Search files and run a script on every result

Tags: unix, awk, find, xargs

I would like to know how to search certain pattern of files in all Sub Directories ( Month wise / Date wise - Sub Directories created). And then, execute a script on the found files.

Step1: For example: currently searching files on this pattern `TT_DETAIL*.gz`.

```
find /cygdrive/c/Test/  -name TT_DETAIL*.gz
```

output#1:

```
/cygdrive/c/Test/Feb2014/TT_DETAIL_20141115.csv.gz
/cygdrive/c/Test/Jan2014/TT_DETAIL_20141110.csv.gz
/cygdrive/c//Test/Mar2014/TT_DETAIL_20141120.csv.gz
```

Step2:

```
zcat TT_DETAIL*.gz | awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=","} { if ($11=="10") print $2,$3,$6,$10,$11,$17}' >Op_TT_Detail.txt
```

cat Op_TT_Detail.txt

```
01-NOV-2014 00:30:53,AAA,ECH,1,10,XXX
01-NOV-2014 00:39:36,BBB,ECH,1,10,XXX
01-NOV-2014 00:39:44,CCC,ECH,1,10,XXX
01-NOV-2014 00:25:20,DDD,ECH,1,10,XXX
```

Have tried to combine the below commands like this, but the steps are in-complete:

```
find /cygdrive/c/Test/  -name TT_DETAIL*.gz | xargs | zcat | awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=","} { if ($11=="10") print $2,$3,$6,$10,$11,$17}' >>Op_TT_DETAIL.txt

find /cygdrive/c/Test/  -name TT_DETAIL*.gz -exec ./MonthwiseData.sh {} \;
```

Where cat MonthwiseData.sh

```
zcat *.gz | awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=","} { if ($11=="10") print $2,$3,$6,$10,$11,$17}' >>Op_TT_Detail.txt
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a `while` loop is the best way to handle these situations:

```
while IFS= read -r file
do
   awk '...' <(zcat "$file")
done < <(find . -type f -name "*gz")
```

You have a `find` command that is sent to a `while` loop. This way, you can process each file separatedly.

Then, it is a matter of performing a basic `awk '...' <(zcat "$file")` or `zcat "$file" | awk '...'`.

In your case:

```
while IFS= read -r file
do
   awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=","} { if ($11=="10") print $2,$3,$6,$10,$11,$17}' <(zcat "$file") >>Op_TT_Detail.txt
done < <(find /cygdrive/c/Test/  -name TT_DETAIL*.gz)
```

#### Test

We have some `gz` files in the current directory:

```
$ for f in *gz; do echo "-- $f --"; zcat "$f"; done-- a.gz --
hello
bye
-- b.gz --
thisisB
bye
```

Let's `find` them and print just the first field on the first line:

```
$ while IFS= read -r file; do awk 'NR==1{print $1}' <(zcat "$file") >> output; done < <(find . -type f -name "*gz")
```

And the output is:

```
$ cat output 
thisisB
hello
```

---

<s>I think you are looking for something like this:</s>

```
find /cygdrive/c/Test/ -name "TT_DETAIL*.gz" -print0 | \
  xargs -0 -I file zcat file | \
  awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=","} { if ($11=="10") print $2,$3,$6,$10,$11,$17}' >>Op_TT_Detail.txt
```

- `find` finds files and `-print0` prints its name.
- `xargs -0` allows you to handle what is coming from the previous pipe. With `-I file` we name it `file`, so that we can then do `zcat file | awk`.

Interesting reading: [xargs: How To Control and Use Command Line Arguments](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-xargs-construct-argument-lists-utility/).

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the find command in tick marks to create an argument list, like:

```
awk '{print $0}' `find . -type f -name 'file*'` > concat_files.txt
```

A simple example doing the same as concatenating all files starting with "file" really. It is just the tick marks I want to emphasize here.