# Search files and run a script on every result - Cont:

Tags: unix, awk, find, xargs

I would like to know how to search certain pattern of files (GunZip Files) in all Sub Directories ( Month wise / Date wise - Sub Directories created). 
And then, execute a script on the found files. Also need to populate FILENAME along with output for tracking purpose and further analysis on that particular files.

Step1: For example: currently searching files on this pattern TT_DETAIL*.gz.

```
find /cygdrive/c/Test/  -name TT_DETAIL*.gz
```

output#1:

```
/cygdrive/c/Test/Feb2014/TT_DETAIL_20141115.csv.gz
/cygdrive/c/Test/Jan2014/TT_DETAIL_20141110.csv.gz
/cygdrive/c//Test/Mar2014/TT_DETAIL_20141120.csv.gz
```

Step2:

```
zcat TT_DETAIL*.gz | awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=","} { if ($11=="10") print $2,$3,$6,$10,$11,$17}' >Op_TT_Detail.txt
```

cat Op_TT_Detail.txt

```
ZZZ,AAA,ECH,1,10,XXX
ZZZ,BBB,ECH,1,10,XXX
ZZZ,CCC,ECH,1,10,XXX
ZZZ,DDD,ECH,1,10,XXX
```

Thanks `fedorqui` for below script is working fine without FILENAME.

```
while IFS= read -r file
do
   awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=","} { if ($11=="10") print $2,$3,$6,$10,$11,$17}' <(zcat "$file") >>Op_TT_Detail.txt
done < <(find /cygdrive/c/Test/  -name TT_DETAIL*.gz)
```

Have tried below command to populate FILENAME along with output for tracking purpose :

```
while IFS= read -r file
do
   awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=","} { if ($11=="10") print $2,$3,$6,$10,$11,$17,FILENAME}' <(zcat "$file") >>Op_TT_Detail.txt
done < <(find /cygdrive/c/Test/  -name TT_DETAIL*.gz)
```

Desired Output:

```
 ZZZ,AAA,ECH,1,10,XXX,/cygdrive/c/Test/Feb2014/TT_DETAIL_20141115.csv.gz
 ZZZ,BBB,ECH,1,10,XXX,/cygdrive/c/Test/Feb2014/TT_DETAIL_20141115.csv.gz
 ZZZ,CCC,ECH,1,10,XXX,/cygdrive/c//Test/Mar2014/TT_DETAIL_20141120.csv.gz 
 ZZZ,DDD,ECH,1,10,XXX,/cygdrive/c//Test/Mar2014/TT_DETAIL_20141120.csv.gz
```

Since FILENAME is not working for *.gz files , should I write" `find /cygdrive/c/Test/  -name TT_DETAIL*.gz` " into another output file 
 then call that output file into script ,  I don't have a write access for source files located server.

Looking for your suggestions !!!

Comment: You've asked many awk questions and yet you're STILL doing absolute beginner things like putting the condition in the action block. Awk scripts are written as `awk '<condition> { <action> }'`, not `awk '{ if (<condition>) <action> }'` and I KNOW you've had previous answers showing you how to pass the value of shell variables to awk scripts. It's pointless us providing answers if you don't learn anything from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice to see you are using the snippet [I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27063298/1983854) in the previous question!

I would use this:

```
while IFS= read -r file
do
   awk -v file="$file" 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=","} \
                        { if ($11=="10") print $2,$3,$6,$10,$11,$17, file}' \
        <(zcat "$file") >>Op_TT_Detail.txt
done < <(find /cygdrive/c/Test/  -name TT_DETAIL*.gz)
```

That is, with `-v file="$file"` you give the file name as a variable to `awk`. And then you use it in your `print` command.

Comment: Fedorqui , Just for curiosity , "1" displayed against my comments is equal to "You are welcome"like that ... or some thing else !!!

Comment: Haha yes, it's like saying: "yeah, I am happy that it worked to you!! I don't know what else to say apart from this, so I will say +1 to make it shorter :))"

Comment: Thanks a ton for sharing and helping others , The above script saves lot of my manual works in Excel / Access !!!

Comment: You are more than welcome, I am very glad to read this. Your questions are always clear and challenging, so I try to answer them because I always end up learning something myself.